# What is PATH_TO_CREDENTIAL_FILE on Running Django on Kubernetes Engine?

Tags: django, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

On step 8 of *Deploying the app to GKE* in [Running Django on Kubernetes Engine](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/kubernetes-engine), it asks you to run this command:

```
kubectl create secret generic cloudsql-oauth-credentials --from-file=credentials.json=[PATH_TO_CREDENTIAL_FILE]
```

What is `PATH_TO_CREDENTIAL_FILE` supposed to be? I'm a bit lost here.

Comment: If you have lost those credentials, go to the GCP Console -> IAM -> Service accounts -> select the service account that you are using. You can then click on `CREATE KEY` to download new credentials. I would cancel the old ones if they are lost and not being used.

Answer (score 1):

As it says in the previous line, it's the "location of the key you downloaded when you created your service account".